# How to sort DB records by parent

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, sorting

I've DB table like this:

```
ID    Name    ParentID    isActive
1      ABC   NULL         true
2      DEF   1            true
3      GHI   1            true
4      JKL   NULL         true
5      MNO   4            true
6      PRS   NULL         true
7      TUV   NULL         true
8      WX    1            true
9      YZ    4            true
10     abc   7            true
```

I get that to a list:

```
var projectList = connection.Where(d=>d.Active);
```

When I get this table to a list, I want to sort them by parent ID. So, the sorted list should be like this: (each row replaced its parent row's below).

- 1 is parent of 2,3 and 8
- 4 is parent of 5 and 9

```
1|ABC
2|DEF
3|GHI
**4|WX**
5|JKL
6|MNO
**7|YZ**
8|PRS
9|TUV
**10|abc**
```

How can I sort this list?

Comment: Is you want sorting with linq or sql?

Comment: You need to use OrderBy method on the list. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: perhaps... `order by ID`

Comment: I use Linq. Do you have an answer? (Parent->Children, Other Parent->It's Children). So I want to list child rows after their parent row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to join the result with itself by distinguishing the parent and child elements. I hope it helped.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var connection = new List<User>()
  {
    new User(1, "ABC", null, true),
    new User(2, "DEF", 1, true),
    new User(3, "GHI", 1, true),
    new User(4, "JKL", null, true),
    new User(5, "MNO", 4, true),
    new User(6, "PRS", null, true),
    new User(7, "TUV", null, true),
    new User(8, "WX", 1, true),
    new User(9, "YZ", 4, true),
    new User(10, "abc", 7, true)
  };


  var filtered = connection.Where(x => x.Active).OrderBy(z => z.ParentID);
  var result = filtered.Where(p => p.ParentID == null).GroupJoin(filtered, parent => parent.ID,
      child => child.ParentID,
      (parent, child) => new {Child = child, Parent = parent})
    .Aggregate(new List<User>(), (outList, tempObj) =>
    {
      outList.Add(tempObj.Parent);
      outList.AddRange(tempObj.Child);       
      return outList;
    });

  foreach (var item in result)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID} | {item.Name} | {item.ParentID}");
  }
}
```

It produces a following output:

`1 | ABC |
2 | DEF | 1
3 | GHI | 1
8 | WX | 1
4 | JKL |
5 | MNO | 4
9 | YZ | 4
6 | PRS |
7 | TUV |
10 | abc | 7`